# CSS layout going crazy in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

All I can say is my layout went crazy in IE8 and I cannot see why. Of course, it looks correct in other current browsers. I have spent many hours trying to figure it out but when I make any changes, they do not fix this issue and send everything haywire in the other browsers. Can someone please take a look? This one is beyond me!

The page:
http://www.careersinmusic.com/sell-my-music.aspx

MANY thanks!!!!
Rich

Comment: Can you explain your problem? What have you tried to solve it? I took 10 seconds to view you page -- don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: What parts are the problems? I'm looking at it in IE8 vs FF4 Beta, and there are very few differences. There are some spacing differences with text etc, but I see no huge huge problems.

Could you be more specific in what you find the issue with? Or maybe a screenshot?

Comment: Please try clicking IE8's "compatibility view" off. When I have it on in IE8 it looks fine. When it is off, which I assume is how the browser is set by default, the DIV miss-align. THANKS for taking a look too. I do appreciate it!

Comment: Actually by default it was Off, and it worked fine. When I turn compatability mode ON for your website it doesn't display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I can see in debugging your IE8 Compatability Mode On code is your lack of clears on the floats.

You should look into how CSS does floating, you must clear the float afterwards otherwise things can get really janky.

To clear a float you put in:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

That will clear both left and right float (eg starting a new section). To just clear one of the floats you can do clear: left; or clear: right;

Here's a tutorial on floats with CSS:

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

Also....honestly....the html and css are a mess. I can barely tell what is going on in some of it....allthough that might just be the asp.net adding in magic to try and 'help' you.

Comment: Well... my CSS and such is all self taught so I work in ways that I understand. I am open to suggestions though. As for the fix, clearing the div has almost totally worked. Its better but the book cover is still not top aligning. Ideas? Also... THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Add a float:left; to #program-book-cover. Also take a look into conditional IE stylesheets, http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/ This will allow you to easily deal with IE only problems.

Answer (score 0):

well first of all 'jQuery' is undefined on line 132?

Comment: That is code straight from MailChimp for adding their form to your website. I have not edited it at all so if it's wrong, I would not know what to do to address it.